# IllegalArgumentException: column x is invalid

Tags: android, sqlite, illegalargumentexception

I have a Listview, populated from a sqlite database. The database is created with:
`egrohDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + EGROH_DB_TABLE_ITEMS +
        " (ident integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "id integer(15), " +`...

To get data from the database I use `rawQueries` and for inserting data I'm using `InsertHelper`. I added one row to the table. And now I'm getting an `IllegalArgumentException`, that mit id row is invalid.

```
06-02 17:48:24.340: E/AndroidRuntime(23200): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-02 17:48:24.340: E/AndroidRuntime(23200): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'id' is invalid
06-02 17:48:24.340: E/AndroidRuntime(23200):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils$InsertHelper.getColumnIndex(DatabaseUtils.java:1078)
06-02 17:48:24.340: E/AndroidRuntime(23200):    at com.y5apps.DatabaseController.insertData(DatabaseController.java:273)
06-02 17:48:24.340: E/AndroidRuntime(23200):    at com.y5apps.EgrohCatalogue.parseData(EgrohCatalogue.java:149)
06-02 17:48:24.340: E/AndroidRuntime(23200):    at com.y5apps.EgrohCatalogue$3.onClick(EgrohCatalogue.java:319)
06-02 17:48:24.340: E/AndroidRuntime(23200):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
06-02 17:48:24.340: E/AndroidRuntime(23200):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-02 17:48:24.340: E/AndroidRuntime(23200):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-02 17:48:24.340: E/AndroidRuntime(23200):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-02 17:48:24.340: E/AndroidRuntime(23200):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-02 17:48:24.340: E/AndroidRuntime(23200):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-02 17:48:24.340: E/AndroidRuntime(23200):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-02 17:48:24.340: E/AndroidRuntime(23200):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-02 17:48:24.340: E/AndroidRuntime(23200):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The error is hown at this line:

```
final int id_c = ih.getColumnIndex("id");
```

I have no idea what this exception means. What to do?

Comment: The second line in the log output referencing the column 'item_id' does not exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create column "id" and are asking for column "item_id"...  not in the code you show but somewhere....

It is in your insert.

Comment: Oh sorry, this was a Copy&Paste-Failure... I tried to change the columns name. It was the new logcat and the 'old' code.

Comment: Did you increment the DB version?  Or uninstall and reinstall the app?  If you didn't then your changes to the DB didn't get made because neither `onCreate` or `onUpgrade` got called...

Comment: It wasn't the typo you mentioned, but it was another one at an other line. Thanks for the suggestion, got me finally to the solution. :)